# Adding classes with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, react-dom

I have a basic component that I'd like to use in multiple instances with differing classes.

```
 <div className="module module--{this.props.classModifier}" ></div>
```

When I render the above using `<...classModifier="red" />` it doesn't affect what is rendered and the browser outputs `{this.props.classModifier}`

Can anybody point out where and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The main reason why this happens is because the `{this.props.classModifier}` is treated as string instead of a variable. You have options. You can use **concatenation** or **interpolation**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be:

You can use interpolation syntax from ES6.

```
<div className={`module module--${this.props.classModifier}`}></div>
```

Comment: Not typically in React projects (for this specific example), although it *does* work. (Adding "why" would be good, too.)

Comment: To plagiarise @T.J.Crowder "Why" would be a very useful extension to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax will be treated as a pure string: `"module module--{this.props.classModifier}"`. If you want to append string using JSX, try this syntax instead `className={"module module--" + this.props.classModifier}`.

Answer (score 1):

As an explanation, if you use double quotes only, you're just rendering a string. It won't get the variable reference like that. You have to split the variable and the string portions by wrapping it with the curly braces:

```
//Template Literals
className={`module module--${this.props.classModifier}`}

//Concatenation
className={"module module--" + this.props.classModifier}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need change code to this:

```
<div className={`module module--${this.props.classModifier}`}></div>
```

Comment: @Ionut - Ah yes. (Huh, normally I do check for edits...)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.props.classModifier` inside a `""` so it will print as it is. Use template strings
Use this

```
 className={`module module--${this.props.classModifier}`}
```